# Generated Rig showing on the z axis

Tags: rigging, axis

When I generate my rig, it generates on the z axis.  I have checked my setting to automatic axis.  see screen shot.  Any thoughts on how to correct this? [image]

Answer (score 1):

I selected the metarig, then went to *Object > Apply Scale*; repeated for *Rotation* and *Location*.

After completing this the rig generated correctly.